# Jersey - JAX-RS Background Thread

Tags: java, json, jersey

I need a java expert for jersey.

Currently i made a jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 application where the application runs with the http server.

Before the http server starts i start a background thread which regularly fills a ArrayList.

Is it possible to have access to this arraylist in the http server to make a response with the background thread arraylist?

It would be perfect! Which logic is here necessary?

Best Regards supercop89